# Xquery textbox disapears after typing xpath query

Tags: sonarqube

When I create a new custom rules on 4.4.1.

I add the xPath query to the textbox but when I save it doesn't really save as when I try to edit the rule, the xquery textbox is empty. Then after when I type it again and save, the xquery textbox disapears from the edit panel, see below screen shot.

Also, when I try to analyze my code with that custom rule enabled it doesn't catch any error.
I created a custom with the xpath query //IDENTIFIER[string-length(@tokenValue) >= 10] just to test if I could make a custom rule works

[image: Xquery textbox not there]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have encountered http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5575 and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5574, they will be fixed in the upcoming 4.5.1

Comment: do you have an idea of when it is going to be?

Comment: Estimated release date is 2014-10-31